# Using an I2C barometer

Tags: sensors, i2c

When buying a barometer for my current project at work, I chose the MikroElektronika click 3 barometer. However, as it turns out, the library for it doesn't exist for Arduino.
I know it uses I2C communication, so I tried connecting the board to my Arduino UNO R3 as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU11aV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I do not know how to use the output of the sensor. Is there a way to access the raw data measured by the sensor and post-process it myself, or is a library needed?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Of course there is a way. There is a document called "Data Sheet" for your barometer IC and there should be everything about communication.

Comment: The datasheet for DPS368 is available at [infinion site](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/datasheets/DPS368-DataSheet.pdf). You can use `wire` library to read the i2c data from it. There are also some information on [Mikroe](https://www.mikroe.com/barometer-3-click) about the board configuration and some c snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I have found MikroElektronika library for the barometer 3. You can get basic idea how to communicate with the sensor.
[MikroElektronika c libraray](https://github.com/MikroElektronika/mikrosdk_click_v2/tree/master/clicks/barometer3)

You can develop your own library based on that one for Arduino or you can read the data sheet of the sensor for more details.

Comment: You have an invalid link

Comment: I have fixed the link

Comment: Hi Arslan, thank you for your answer. However, it seems this library is only usable with MikroE compilers? Or is ther a way to import it on Arduino?

Comment: The code is in C, however, a quick looks at the [library source file](https://github.com/MikroElektronika/mikrosdk_click_v2/blob/bc5bb929945748fda1a9d11d9e97a2344f3858ea/clicks/barometer3/lib/include/barometer3.h#L404), it does allows to be compiled in C++.  So you need to copy the `barometer3.c` and `barometer3.h` into your arduino project file, copy the `main.c` to your project folder and rename it to `barometer3.ino` (or your project_name.ino), and modify it to the Arduino sketch format, and if compiler complains, do the modification to the source code or your sketch to make it work.

Comment: You need to modify the file to be able to use them